# Application dependency not found while release by the build agent

Tags: azure-devops, .net-standard-2.0

My .NETStandard library works fine locally on Visual Studio. But, when I release the WebApi containing my .NETStandard library the release proces failed on the EF Core Migrations step. 
I use the Deploy Entity Framework Core Migrations release task by @bendayconsulting. The error message I receive is n assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (MySecondMobileApp.ServerData.deps.json) was not found:
package: 'Google.Protobuf', version: '3.5.1'
path: 'lib/netstandard1.0/Google.Protobuf.dll

When I look at the packages folder at my solution there is no Google.Protobuf assembly. The assembly is stored at my global NuGet folder and is part of the MySql.EntityFrameWorkCore NuGet package. The MySql.EntityFramworkCore package is also installed at my user's global NuGet folder. How can I get these packages in the solution's folder? I think that is the answer of my problem.

My deps file looks like this:

```
{
  "runtimeTarget": {
    "name": ".NETStandard,Version=v2.0/",
    "signature": "19d3dd659b5fa2adabeefcff78ce8381da3d4fe9"
  },
  "compilationOptions": {},
  "targets": {
    ".NETStandard,Version=v2.0": {},
    ".NETStandard,Version=v2.0/": {
      "ClassLibrary1/1.0.0": {
        "dependencies": {
          "Google.Protobuf": "3.6.1",
          "NETStandard.Library": "2.0.3"
        },
        "runtime": {
          "ClassLibrary1.dll": {}
        }
      },
      "Google.Protobuf/3.6.1": {
        "dependencies": {
          "NETStandard.Library": "2.0.3"
        },
        "runtime": {
          "lib/netstandard1.0/Google.Protobuf.dll": {
            "assemblyVersion": "3.6.1.0",
            "fileVersion": "3.6.1.0"
          }
        }
      },
      "Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms/1.1.0": {},
      "NETStandard.Library/2.0.3": {
        "dependencies": {
          "Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms": "1.1.0"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "libraries": {
    "ClassLibrary1/1.0.0": {
      "type": "project",
      "serviceable": false,
      "sha512": ""
    },
    "Google.Protobuf/3.6.1": {
      "type": "package",
      "serviceable": true,
      "sha512": "sha512-D/h9IZl76jjfM5VlPzG235Zdys9RKXNLYbRGm2fa6Y2UshTqAvYBPIydNOvNTEa24DER/m/zvelHlLO9n1GtNQ==",
      "path": "google.protobuf/3.6.1",
      "hashPath": "google.protobuf.3.6.1.nupkg.sha512"
    },
    "Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms/1.1.0": {
      "type": "package",
      "serviceable": true,
      "sha512": "sha512-kz0PEW2lhqygehI/d6XsPCQzD7ff7gUJaVGPVETX611eadGsA3A877GdSlU0LRVMCTH/+P3o2iDTak+S08V2+A==",
      "path": "microsoft.netcore.platforms/1.1.0",
      "hashPath": "microsoft.netcore.platforms.1.1.0.nupkg.sha512"
    },
    "NETStandard.Library/2.0.3": {
      "type": "package",
      "serviceable": true,
      "sha512": "sha512-st47PosZSHrjECdjeIzZQbzivYBJFv6P2nv4cj2ypdI204DO+vZ7l5raGMiX4eXMJ53RfOIg+/s4DHVZ54Nu2A==",
      "path": "netstandard.library/2.0.3",
      "hashPath": "netstandard.library.2.0.3.nupkg.sha512"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Configure a [package management feed (Azure Artifacts)](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/artifacts/) and push your internal packages to it, then use a NuGet restore task in your build prior to building to restore the packages from your internal feed.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Unfortunately that is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I resolved this problem. First, I will apologize from my incomplete question. I had to told stackoverflow my whole problem. My base problem is that I couldn't release my WebAPI containing EntityFrameworkCore for MySql on a Hosted2017 build agent in Azure Devops. The Build Agent also excutes the database migrations.

After some thoughts I relealized that a MySqlConnection not is supported by .NET by default -> you have to install additional client software on the build agent. Unfortunately the Microsoft build agents don't have the capability to establish a MySQLConnection between the build agent and the MySQL database server.

What completely vage is for me at this moment is the fact that the API WebServer on AWS supports this databaseconnection by default. My WebAPI is working perfect on the webserver.

The solution for me to make the build agent work with MySQL was to install an on premise build agent and install MySQL Workbench to install the MYSQL software. 
Now the build agent is working fine. The migrations are successfully executed.